# Custom Layout in Minimalistic Text?

Tags: screen, app-widgets

I'm using the free version of minimalistic text on android 2.3.7 and I can't seem to find any option for custom layout. There are references to it on the net but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Is that a pro only feature or have they removed the option altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're talking about Tasker, have you seen this comment from [their Google Play page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.devmil.minimaltext):

> Tasker integration:
>
> 1. add a Locale variable to your layout and set the variable name (click it)
> 2. in Tasker select Plugins -> Minimalistic Text for an action
> 3. Click "Edit", a new activity starts
> 4. enter the name of the variable and the text that should be displayed for this variable (you can use Tasker variables)

Everything else is customizable. Add a new row, and use the `+` button to select and add new elements by checking them.

Answer (score 0):

After you create a widget, you'll be able to customize its settings as you see in the flow below. In the 3rd image, the layout section is the 3rd tab (or whatever it's called).

[image]

Comment: I'm not talking about editing a *predefined* layout. I'm talking about creating a custom layout from scratch where you can display Tasker variables. See this: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-gorgeous-textonly-widgets-free-minimalistic-text-android/